# TF Slim eval_image_classifier 0 accuracy on pre-trained ckpts

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Running tf slim's [eval_image_classifier.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/eval_image_classifier.py) with the inception_v3, inception_v4 and resnet_v2_152 checkpoints pre-trained by google, all give 0% accuracy consistently. Changing the code a little to add TruePositives, TrueNegatives, FalsePositives and FalseNegatives as metrics shows this.

```
eval/TruePositives[22613] 
eval/TrueNegatives[0]    
eval/FalsePositives[27387] 
eval/Accuracy[0] eval/FalseNegatives[0]
eval/Recall_5[0.0004]
```

The command I'm using is:

```
python eval_image_classifier.py --checkpoint_path=inception_v4.ckpt --eval_dir=. --dataset_name=imagenet --dataset_split_name=validation --dataset_dir=/imagenet --model_name=inception_v4
```

I've tried with setting the preprocessing_name to inception and the eval_image_size to 299 as well but this makes no difference to the result. Any ideas on whats causing this? I can't find anyone on any forums that have the same issues